# How to read headers on Blazor Razor Page?

Tags: blazor

I have a Razor Page and want to read headers from requests, but I can't to find how to do it.
How can I do it?

```
@page  "/"
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager;


<div class="section">
</div>

@code {

    private string header;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // how to do it here
    }
}
```

Comment: For serverside read this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0 (is about security but I hope also works for any other HttpContext request data)

Answer (score 12):

I found easy method for reading headers

In first, adds a default implementation for the IHttpContextAccessor service

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then it nessary for getting headers by header' name from request of page:

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

@code {

    private string needParameter { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        needParameter = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["parameterName"];
    }
}
```